# How to emulate a mouse?

Tags: apk, touchscreen, virtualization, mouse, virtualbox

I am running Android 4.3 "jelly bean" in a VirtualBox VM. Google has released an ISO of an x86 port on [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list). It's a fairly straightforward installation, and easy to setup. You can find a tutorial [here](https://techglimpse.com/run-android-os-windows-linux-virtual-machine/) if you need help. But let's get back on subject.

Anyways, I have successfully installed it. It does not seem to have mouse integration, which I *desperately need.* My laptop which I am running it on does not have a touchscreen. It is a 64-bit Dell something-or-other laptop I received from a friend, and it is running Ubuntu 16.10. Is there any available APKs or workarounds for the mouse? I can use the mouse, but no pointer displays. For example, I can click and drag the top menu bar that displays notifications, battery, etc. and open that, or click buttons (if I'm careful), or use it as if it were my finger. I simply need it to display the mouse pointer. The only workaround *I* can think of is unlock the developer tools and use the mouse tracking option that draws a line when you tap. However, that only works if I click and drag.

The question: Are there any APK's or workarounds for displaying a mouse pointer or emulating a mouse, and if there is/are, how can I use/activate/install/get them?

**edit**: This isn't something I can't live without. I'm just experimenting, maybe going to do a little android gaming just for fun. I can do most of the UI navigation with the keyboard, but a mouse would make things much easier. Also, I am looking for a *no-price, costless* workaround. That said, I'd rather not do anything like buy a controller.

~ P

Comment: 4.3 does support displaying a mouse pointer, and it Should Just Work when you start using the mouse.

Comment: @DanHulme I have the mouse connected at all times. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have found a temporary answer. In the "Input" taskbar menu of Vitualbox, there is a mouse integration option. Left unchecked, Android draws the mouse pointer. However, if Mouse Integration is on, it relies on the host OS, which does not work. This option is less convenient, but it works for now. If anyone has any recommendations to permanently fix this, please post an answer.

~ P